# Fortran doesn't call FINAL on arrays or program variables

Tags: fortran, destructor, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a type, that has a routine with the FINAL attribute:

```
module m_test

   type t_test
      integer :: a
   contains
      final free
   end type t_test

contains
   subroutine free(h)
      implicit none

      type(t_test) :: h
      write (*,*) 'close: ', h%a
   end subroutine free
end module m_test

subroutine no_free_call()
   use m_test
   implicit none
   type(t_test) :: h(3)

   h(1)%a = 2
end subroutine no_free_call

subroutine free_call()
   use m_test
   implicit none
   type(t_test) :: h

   h%a = 3
end subroutine free_call


program main
   use m_test
   implicit none

   type(t_test) :: h

   call no_free_call()
   call free_call()

   h%a = 1
end program main
```

This is it's output:

```
 close:            3
```

which is the same for gfortran 8.2.0 and ifort 18.0.1 20171018.

As you can see routines marked FINAL are called, if they are a scalar in a subroutine, but not if:

- they are a scalar in the `program main`-part
- they are in a static array in a subroutine running out of scope
- they are in an allocatable array running out of scope
- they are in an allocatable array beeing deallocated

This make little sense. Is this a compiler bug or is it standard fortran? Is the any way to fix this?

Comment: The final subroutine must be specialized in the sense of matching the argument rank and kind. Try making your final procedure elemental (actually, impure elemental, because of the print statement) or writing specific procedures for each case.

Comment: That is also correct and we had a recent duplicate for the rank issue. I forgot it.